# Combining multiple models for one controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, model-view-controller, pug

I have these 2 controllers:

story.js

```
const Story = require('../models/Story');

exports.getStories = (req, res, next) => {
  Story.find()
  .then((stories) => {
    res.render('story', {title:'StoryTata', stories});
  })
  .catch(() => { res.send('Sorry!'); });
  };
```

ask.js

```
const Ask = require('../models/Ask');

exports.getAsks = (req, res, next) => {
  Ask.find()
  .then((asks) => {
    res.render('ask', {title:'AskTata', asks});
  })
  .catch(() => { res.send('Sorry!'); });
  };
```

And both these controllers work fine with their coupled views (stories.pug and ask.pug)

I am unable figure out my next controller where both of these controllers come together to create a dashboard type view.

dashboard controller --

```
const Story = require('../models/Story');
const Ask = require('../models/Ask');
/**
 * GET /
 * Home page.
 */



exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
  Story.find()
  Ask.find()
  .then((stories, asks) => {
    res.render('home', {stories, asks});
  })
  .catch(() => { res.send('Sorry!'); });
  };
```

I will requesting getHome from my home.pug file.

What should be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Trying with Promise.all and no luck either... exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
Promise.all([Story.find(), Ask.find()])
.then((stories, asks) => {
res.render('home', {stories, asks});
})
.catch(() => { res.send('Sorry!'); });
};

Comment: What are you getting in the response?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `async-await` approach, like this:

```
exports.getHome = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const stories = await Story.find();
    const asks = await Ask.find();
    res.render('home', {stories, asks});
  } catch(e) {
    res.send('Sorry!');
  }
};
```